# r3.xlarge vs t2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and have been tasked to look at ways to optimize cost. I have gone through the best practices and strategies to do that:

- Instance Right Sizing
- Using Reserved Instances (RI) & Spot instances (SI) as appropriate (over On-Demand)
- Auto Scaling Storage (Reduced Redundancy, Glacier)
- Tagging strategies

However, I have specific questions around the instance type. Apparently, we have a **r3.xlarge** (On-Demand) instance used for demos (for new clients) with 240 GB EBS (i.e. 4 CPU, 30.5 GB RAM), therefore it's not used very frequently.

Questions :

1) Will replacing it with a **t2** instance give any cost benefits (in medium to long term) without degrading performance (or any other adverse effects)?

2) If so, which t2 variant can be used (t2.xlarge, t2.2xlarge etc)?

Sorry for my ignorance if this is not the proper place for the question, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can try the http://serverfault.com/ site for such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Amazon EC2 instance that is **used infrequently**, then the best way to save money is to **stop the instance**. On-Demand instances are charged only when they are running. (EBS volume storage will continue to be charged, but there will be no EC2 charge.)

Therefore, the best plan for your situation is:

- Confirm that the current **instance size is appropriate** for your use-case (`r3.xlarge` has 30.5GB of RAM -- do you need that much memory?)
- **Stop** the instance when it is not in use
- **Start** the instance when it is required again

Answer (score 3):

T2 instances will only save you some money on smaller instances. Bigger ones, like `t2.xlarge` has no advantage over let's say memory optimized instances unless you need burstable processing resources for a period of time. The amount of available memory will be the same.

You can compare the specs and prices [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/). As you see, `t2.xlarge` costs $0.243 and `r4.large` costs $0.24 per hour. Both have (approximately) 16 GBs of memory, the latter has 4 vCPUs though (these are for Windows instances / Ireland).

Finally, note that it all depends on your usage. The T instances are more suitable for test and development environments.